# 404 error when load FineUI axd file on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, axd

I deploy FineUI example project on IIS7, but got 404 error from http network when loading .axd files. Any idea the root cause?

Comment: .axd mime type is there in your iis mime types?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will double check this setting on iis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe caused by IIS7 integrated mode.If it is IIS Integrated Mode,You need to add information to system.webServer section:

```
<add name="FineUIResAxd" verb="GET" path="res.axd" type="FineUI.ResourceHandler, FineUI”/>
```

Complete System.WebServer is as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="FineUIScriptModule" type="FineUI.ScriptModule, FineUI"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="FineUIResAxd" verb="GET" path="res.axd" type="FineUI.ResourceHandler, FineUI"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

If IIS is Classic Mode,need to add httpModules and httpHandlers below system.web section:

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add assembly="FineUIPro" namespace="FineUIPro" tagPrefix="f"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>

    <httpModules>
        <add name="FineUIProScriptModule" type="FineUIPro.ScriptModule, FineUIPro"/>
    </httpModules>

    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET" path="res.axd" type="FineUIPro.ResourceHandler, FineUIPro" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
<system.web>
```

When developing in VS, the default built-in IIS Express server is used. You can easily change IIS Express to Classic or Integrated Mode.
1.Choose project in VS, then click F4.
2.Display properties window, change mode.